# I am always seen as online on Google Chat/Hangout

Tags: offline, google-hangouts

How can I make myself offline so that noone can see that I am available. I am unable to find this option after GTalk -> Hangout upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the availability option has been deprecated in hangout. To make yourself invisible or so, either you have to downgrade to gtalk or the easiest way you can do this by going to your gmail account from your pc. There you should find this availability option.

Answer (score 2):

Open hangouts app -> Preference -> Account -> Logout.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this, other than to disable the hangout application itself. (Go to Applications - Hangount - click disable)

Answer (score 1):

I think i have an option which help to be invisible in normal gmail logged in mode.

1. Log in through hangout.
2. Click on the down arrow near "New conversation". It will let us do some settings on our profile.
3. Uncheck the first 3 option. i.e. Show when i was last seen online, Show which device you're on and Show when you are in a video or phone call on your device.
4. After uncheking the all 3 options click sign out from hangout.
5. Check in the gmail... If u r still in available mode. Then change the status into invisible in gmail.

I think u guys will smile after that.......:)

Answer (score 0):

The sign off status will not take effect immediately (well at least for me it's like that). Give or take half an hour, I can see my ID completely logged off.

And it's of course not as long as 30 days for sure.